# What is that springy thing on the head of the tripod?

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, support-equipment

There are two thing on the head of the tripod, one is the screw and the other is this springy thing. I always wondered, what does it do?

[image]

Comment: Already answered here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93119/what-is-the-point-of-the-depressible-peg-on-a-quick-release-plate/93120 It's an anti-rotation pin.